# Table of alcohol densities vs temperature

Tags: temperature, alcohol

I'm working with a physical copy of Stevenson Reeves Practical Alcohol Tables Vol 2. I'm doing a lot of calculations that involve temperature/density changes. I am looking for a legal/paid for/online version of the tables that I can import into excel. Does anyone have a table that might help?

Comment: I've seen plenty of graphs for pure ethanol and water online. Liquid mixtures can be non-linear though so calculating them can actually be erroneous